# DataPicker jQuery doesn't work with @Html.EditorFor in MVC ASP.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I found jQuery DataPicker (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#slider_examples).

But it doesn't work with @HTML.EditorFor, why?

```
@*working*@
<input type="text" name="basic_example_1" id="basic_example_1" value="">

@*not working*@
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eventstart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "basic_example_1" } })

        <script>
        $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker($.timepicker.regional['pl']);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the 2nd example by id (#basic_example_1) while you give it a class. So trying using:

```
$('.basic_example_1').datetimepicker($.timepicker.regional['pl']);
```